# SQL nesting BEGIN END Blocks gives SQL Error (102)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, nested, block

I'm getting the following error for this simple piece of SQL code. Any ideas why? Any BEGIN ... END block causes this error to occur

/* SQL Error (156): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'. */

```
DECLARE @PROCESSEDCOUNT INT = 0
WHILE (@PROCESSEDCOUNT < 10)
BEGIN
    SET @PROCESSEDCOUNT +=1
    IF 1=1
    BEGIN
        -- Stuff happens here
    END
END
```

This is running on SQL Server - MSSQL15

Comment: Because you need to add action between `BEGIN` and `END`

Comment: Sadly, just adding actions doesn't help. This code comes from a statement with lots of action in the block. I get the same error

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cc85db029c4594c4b16ee263e7e4763

Comment: That's strange. Then my inner statements must be causing the issue. Thanks @D-Shih

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put something in between the BEGIN and END block
For example:

```
DECLARE @PROCESSEDCOUNT INT= 1

WHILE (@PROCESSEDCOUNT < 10)
BEGIN
    SET @PROCESSEDCOUNT +=1
    IF 1=1
    BEGIN
        PRINT '1'
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need more than a comment in a begin/end block.

Try the following

```
IF 1=1
    BEGIN
      SELECT @PROCESSEDCOUNT 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any condition for the inner BEGIN...END. You can remove it.

```
DECLARE @PROCESSEDCOUNT INT = 0
WHILE (@PROCESSEDCOUNT < 10)
BEGIN
    SET @PROCESSEDCOUNT +=1
        -- Stuff happens here
END
```